# Perl CGI::Simple under PSGI

Tags: perl, psgi

I am using CGI::Simple in a simple application that I want it to support PSGI, I am not going to use any ready made frameworks, I did a lot of search a bout PSGI support for CGI::Simple but did not find any module on CPAN. By luck I found someone on [this site](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tociyuki/20100131/1264918747) with a module named `CGI::Simple::PSGI` which does not exist on CPAN. Is it safe to include this module with my app, I am not sure why the authors did not upload it to cpan site. I contacted the emails of the modules but got not reply.

Below is the content of this module in case the link is changed.

```
package CGI::Simple::PSGI;
use strict;
use 5.008_001;
our $VERSION = '0.001_002';

use base qw(CGI::Simple);

if ($CGI::Simple::VERSION lt '1.111') {
    no warnings 'redefine';
    *CGI::Simple::_internal_read = sub($\$;$) {
        my ($self, $buffer, $len) = @_;
        $len = 4096 if !defined $len;
        if (exists $self->{psgi_env}{'psgi.input'}) {
            $self->{psgi_env}{'psgi.input'}->read($$buffer, $len);
        }
        elsif ( $self->{'.mod_perl'} ) {
            my $r = $self->_mod_perl_request();
            $r->read( $$buffer, $len );
        }
        else {
            read STDIN, $$buffer, $len;
        }
    };
}

sub new {
    my($class, $env) = @_;
    my $self = bless {
        psgi_env     => $env,
        use_tempfile => 1,
    }, $class;

    local *ENV = $env;
    $self->_initialize_globals;
    $self->_store_globals;
    $self->_read_parse($self->env->{'psgi.input'});

    $self;
}

sub _mod_perl { return 0 }

sub env {
    $_[0]->{psgi_env};
}

# copied and rearanged from CGI::Simple::header
sub psgi_header {
    my($self, @p) = @_;
    require CGI::Simple::Util;
    my @header;
    my(
        $type, $status, $cookie, $target, $expires, $nph, $charset,
        $attachment, $p3p, @other
    ) = CGI::Simple::Util::rearrange([
        ['TYPE', 'CONTENT_TYPE', 'CONTENT-TYPE'],
        'STATUS', ['COOKIE', 'COOKIES'], 'TARGET',
        'EXPIRES', 'NPH', 'CHARSET',
        'ATTACHMENT','P3P',
    ], @p);

    $type ||= 'text/html' unless defined($type);
    if (defined $charset) {
        $self->charset($charset);
    } else {
        $charset = $self->charset if $type =~ /^text\//;
    }
    $charset ||= '';

    # rearrange() was designed for the HTML portion, so we
    # need to fix it up a little.
    my @other_headers;
    for (@other) {
        # Don't use \s because of perl bug 21951
        next unless my($header,$value) = /([^ \r\n\t=]+)=\"?(.+?)\"?$/;
        $header =~ s/^(\w)(.*)/"\u$1\L$2"/e;
        push @other_headers, $header, $self->unescapeHTML($value);
    }

    $type .= "; charset=$charset"
        if     $type ne ''
           and $type !~ /\bcharset\b/
           and defined $charset
           and $charset ne '';

    # Maybe future compatibility.  Maybe not.
    my $protocol = $self->{psgi_env}{SERVER_PROTOCOL} || 'HTTP/1.0';

    push @header, "Status", $status if $status;
    push @header, "Window-Target", $target if $target;
    if ($p3p) {
        $p3p = join ' ',@$p3p if ref $p3p eq 'ARRAY';
        push @header, "P3P", qq{policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="$p3p"};
    }

    # push all the cookies -- there may be several
    if ($cookie) {
        my(@cookie) = ref $cookie eq 'ARRAY' ? @{$cookie} : $cookie;
        for (@cookie) {
            my $cs = eval{ $_->can('as_string') } ? $_->as_string : "$_";
            push @header, "Set-Cookie", $cs if $cs ne '';
        }
    }
    # if the user indicates an expiration time, then we need
    # both an Expires and a Date header (so that the browser is
    # uses OUR clock)
    $expires = 'now'
      if $self->no_cache;    # encourage no caching via expires now
    push @header, 'Expires', CGI::Simple::Util::expires($expires, 'http')
      if $expires;
    push @header, 'Date', CGI::Simple::Util::expires(0, 'http')
      if defined $expires || $cookie || $nph;
    push @header, 'Pragma', 'no-cache' if $self->cache or $self->no_cache;
    push @header, 'Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=\"$attachment\""
      if $attachment;
    push @header, @other;
    push @header, 'Content-Type', $type if $type;

    $status ||= "200";
    $status =~ s/\D*$//;

    return $status, \@header;
}

# The list is auto generated and modified with:
# perl -nle '/^sub (\w+)/ and $sub=$1; \
#   /^}\s*$/ and do { print $sub if $code{$sub} =~ /([\%\$]ENV|http\()/; undef $sub };\
#   $code{$sub} .= "$_\n" if $sub; \
#   /^\s*package [^C]/ and exit' \
# `perldoc -l CGI`
for my $method (qw(
    url_param
    upload
    upload_info
    parse_query_string
    cookie
    raw_cookie
    header
    MyFullUrl
    PrintEnv
    auth_type
    content_length
    content_type
    document_root
    gateway_interface
    path_translated
    referer
    remote_addr
    remote_host
    remote_ident
    remote_user
    request_method
    script_name
    server_name
    server_port
    server_protocol
    server_software
    user_name
    user_agent
    virtual_host
    path_info
    accept
    http
    https
    protocol
    url
)) {
    no strict 'refs';
    *$method = sub {
        my $self  = shift;
        my $super = "SUPER::$method";
        local *ENV = $self->{psgi_env};
        $self->$super(@_);
    };
}

sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;
    CGI::Simple::_initialize_globals();
}

1;

__END__

=head1 NAME

CGI::Simple::PSGI - Enable your CGI/Simple.pm aware applications to adapt PSGI protocol

=head1 VERSION

0.001_002

=head1 SYNOPSIS

  use CGI::Simple::PSGI;

  sub app {
      my $env = shift;
      # set CGI::Simple's global control variables
      local $CGI::Simple::DISABLE_UPLOADS = 0;    # enable upload
      local $CGI::Simple::POST_MAX = 1024;        # max size on POST
      my $q = CGI::Simple::PSGI->new($env);
      return [ $q->psgi_header, [ $body ] ];
  }

=head1 DESCRIPTION

This module extends L<CGI::Simple> to use in some web applications
under the PSGI servers. This is a experimental branch from L<CGI::PSGI>
module for L<CGI> by Tatsuhiko Miyagawa.

=head1 AUTHOR

MIZUTANI Tociyuki C<< tociyuki@google.com >>.
Tatsuhiko Miyagawa E<lt>miyagawa@bulknews.netE<gt>

=head1 LICENSE

This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the same terms as Perl itself.

=head1 SEE ALSO

L<CGI::Simple> L<CGI::PSGI>

=cut
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tatsuhiko Miyagawa is the author of PSGI and Plack, and MIZUTANI Tociyuki has made [contributions to CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~tociyuki/). It looks like the latter's email address is not correct in the code you have pasted above, though.

There is also [Nile::HTTP::PSGI](http://search.cpan.org/~mewsoft/Nile-0.44/lib/Nile/HTTP/PSGI.pm) on CPAN which appears to be from the same codebase with a couple of tweaks and an additional method added.

As with any free software, it's up to you whether or not you use it, but at least there is some credibility behind the authors of this code.